# slice() of the input content

Tags: javascript, angular, slice

I'm working on an assignment in Angular where the user has to put some content in an input field and when it's more than 27 the result should be the first 27 characters followed by "...". I am using the slice() method but, even though the code compiles and runs it does not make the result shorter. I'm still getting the whole input even if it's, let's say, 50 characters.

HTML:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="input1" (keyup)="counter($event)">
<button (click)="shortener()">Make me shorter!</button><br>
{{ notification }}<br>
{{ shorter }}
```

component.ts:

```
export class First27Component implements OnInit {

  public input1: string;
  public shorter: string;
  public notification: string;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  counter(event){
  this.input1=event.target.value;
  }

  shortener() {
    let inputLength: number = this.input1.length
    console.log(inputLength)
    if (inputLength >27) {
    this.shorter = this.input1.slice(0,27)+"..."
    } else {
    this.notification = "Jest mniej niż 27 znaków. Szkoda skracać!"
    }
    this.shorter = this.input1
    console.log(this.shorter)
  }

}
```

What's wrong with it? And maybe it would be better to use the RegEx instead? Thanks for any hints and suggestions! :)

Comment: Can you provide a JSbin or jsfiddle example?

Comment: @ShobiDobi - https://stackblitz.com/edit/k-rapacz-angular-day1-2zhqpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of slice use substring

```
  shortener() {
    let inputLength: number = this.input1.length
    console.log(inputLength)
    if (inputLength >27) {
    this.shorter = this.input1.substring(0,27)+"..."
    } else {
    this.notification = "Jest mniej niż 27 znaków. Szkoda skracać!"
    }
    console.log(this.shorter)
  }
```

And remove this line `this.shorter = this.input1`

Answer (score 1):

This is no the right way to do it, as you might not want to lose the data by trimming it. The best practice would be to store the complete string and only show a part of it with `...` at the end.

For that, use `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. This will append `...` at the end if the text overflows a fixed width.

Here is a complete guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/

Comment: thanks! But am I really losing the data in a situation where the sliced part is assigned to a new variable?

Comment: Even if you don't lose the data, that's an overhead to assign it to a new variable. And why to spend so much effort, if there are ready-made solutions available for such use cases

Answer (score 1):

After you make the shorter string you assign to it the long string just changes it...
from this:

```
 this.shorter= this.input1
```

to this:

```
 this.input1 = this.shorter
```